# Android get filefrom assets or res

Tags: android, assets, android-resources, android-image

I'm trying to package an image with my app, this image wont be used by any activity or layout, it's going to be used by an inner process which takes the File as parameter...

I didn't find any way to get the file or filepath from an asset or resource, all methods like:

```
        context.getAssets().open();
        context.getResources().openRawResource()
```

return an input stream to read the bytes from the file, but i need to File itself or the filepath (in order to make new File(filepath) and pass it as parameter to an third party API)

how can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither assets nor resources are files on the filesystem of the device. Your choices are:

1. Convince the developers of the third-party API to [offer a better API](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/08/07/for-android-apis-think-streams-not-files.html), or
2. Use the methods in your question to get an `InputStream`, and use that to copy the bytes to some file that you control (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`), so you can use that file

Comment: do you know a simple answer for "what is an apk?" the traditional java bundle (jar) can address files to the running program why apk cant

Comment: @RafaelLima: "the traditional java bundle (jar) can address files to the running program" -- you have to do the same thing that I described for Java resources packaged in JARs. `File` only works with ordinary files on the filesystem. It does not work with things *inside* files, such as the contents of JARs, the contents of APKs, or the contents of other ZIP files.